# Проблема с запрашиванием разрешения PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE react-native

Tags: javascript, файловая-система, react-native

У меня проблема с запрашиванием разрешений в react native. Мне нужны разрешения на доступ к чтению и записи всех файлов (в том числе данных других приложений, но начнем пока с малого) на устройстве.
вот код который должен запрашивать разрешения и описание что он делает не так:

1. запрашивает разрешение на доступ только к медиа контент
   `PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`
2. вообще ничего не запрашивает
   `PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`

как вы поняли прочитать файлы у меня не получилось. Заранее спасибо за объяснение что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 0):

К тегу `<application>` в файле `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` добавьте атрибут `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  ...
</application>
```